# TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.db.collection is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I saw that this question was posted 2 days ago. I tried the fixes that solved it for someone else, however I still can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong. I am trying to get a contact page working using React. Thanks in advance!

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import { db } from '../firebase';


const Contact = () => {

  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    db.collection('contacts')
    .add({
      name:name,
      email:email,
      message:message,
    })
    .then(() => {
      alert('Message submitted ' );
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      alert(error.message);
    });

    setName('');
    setEmail('');
    setMessage('');
  };


  return (



  )
}

export default Contact
```

firebase.js file:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: ""
};


const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app)
export { db }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not exporting Firestore as `db` but the whole Firebase app instance. Try refactoring your code such that it exports Firestore instance as `db`:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app)
export { db }
```

Also you are using the new Modular SDK (v9) which has a completely new syntax. I'd recommend following the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) to understand it. Your query should be:

```js
import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 
import {db} from "../firebase"

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    addDoc(collection(db, "contacts"), {
      name:name,
      email:email,
      message:message,
    })
    .then(() => {
      alert('Message submitted ' );
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      alert(error.message);
    });

    setName('');
    setEmail('');
    setMessage('');
  };
```

Comment: It's giving me the same error and referencing my Contact.js file saying that db.collection is not a function..

Comment: @ChrisPesar try restarting your web app server once. Make sure you have saved the files.

Comment: Same thing.. The form loads but when I click to submit the data I get the error

Comment: I'm sorry.. What I have is the latest code, I just left out what's in the return( )

Comment: Yeah.. TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.db.collection is not a function

Comment: Where it looks like the error is coming from:

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        db.collection('contacts').add({
          name: name,
          email: email,
          message: message,
        })
        .then(() => {
          alert('Message submitted ' );
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          alert(error.message);
        });

        setName('');
        setEmail('');
        setMessage('');
  
      };

Comment: @ChrisPesar please try the updated answer

Comment: @ChrisPesar you can accept this answer by clicking the checkmark if it helps you :D